# Attempting YouTube upload through Python API gives 'Developer key required for this operation' Error

Tags: python, youtube, gdata

I am attempting to upload a video to YouTube using the developer key that I obtained as paired with credentials for a particular user. It seems to me that my YoutubeService object should have the proper developer credentials, but the server comes back with 403: Developer key required for this operation.

```
import gdata
import gdata.youtube
import gdata.youtube.service
client_id = 'dummy-client'
developer_key = 'xxxxxxx......'
youtube_user = 'sampleuser@gmail.com'
youtube_password = 'passwordgoeshere'
yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService(client_id, developer_key)
yt_service.ssl = True
yt_service.developer_id = developer_key
yt_service.client_id = client_id
yt_service.email = youtube_user
yt_service.password = youtube_password
yt_service.source = client_id
yt_service.ProgrammaticLogin() #Successfully login with the developer key and the user's credentials

my_media_group = gdata.media.Group(
    title=gdata.media.Title(text='video.avi'),
    description=gdata.media.Description(description_type='plain', text='My Video'),
    keywords=gdata.media.Keywords(text=''),
    category=[gdata.media.Category(
    text='Autos',
    scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat', label='Autos')],
    player=None,
    private=gdata.media.Private()
)
video_entry = gdata.youtube.YouTubeVideoEntry(media=my_media_group)
video_file_location = '/path/to/video.avi'

#Use the supposedly authenticated and developer_id associated YoutubeService object to upload the video
new_entry = yt_service.InsertVideoEntry(video_entry, video_file_location)

#Receive the following error:
#
#Traceback (most recent call last):
#  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
#  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdata/youtube/service.py", line 661, in InsertVideoEntry
#    raise YouTubeError(e.args[0])
#gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeError: {'status': 403, 'body': 'Developer key required     for this operation', 'reason': 'Forbidden'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your developer ID and developer key are different things. You need to put your key (which is associated with your account rather than a specific registered application) into yt_service.developer_key